# Javascript bug in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, classname

Here is the Webpage with the bug. (link has been removed)

The webpage looks great in chrome as always, but has 2 bugs in IE8:

1. The search field only spans half the width of the search box in IE.
2. The tabs on top of the search box don't work in IE.

I'll take all the help I can get with these bugs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The text gets cut off in FF too. Browsers (and OSes) render fonts slightly differently, meaning text will overlap if you're not careful. Why not just make the text box bigger? Also, can you explain (or show, with a screenshot) what IE does(n't) do for those of us who don't have IE?

Comment: I checked it in Firefox 6.0.2: The text does get cut off but the tabs work as expected.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution, so the text in the search field doesn't get cut off. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

For the tabs thing, try explicitly declaring your tabs variable, i.e. `var tabs = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'tab');`

Answer (score 0):

The field getting cut off is because it's being sized by the font-size, defining margin right/left isn't going to size it usually. Tab behavior is the same for me in both IE9 and FF6. What is it you're observing that isn't occuring?

Comment: As for tab behavior: The tabs don't respond in any way when clicked in IE8.

Comment: Could you go into greater depth with your explanation of the search field being cut off. I get what your saying about certain browsers applying a certain width to the text field with respect to the `font-size`, but why would they ignoring my style declarations for width and cut off the content? Any solutions? P.S. I don't get what your saying about the margins. What do they have to do with this? Thanks!

Comment: From what I saw in IE (F12) there was no width being applied to it. The only thing was margin right and left, but that won't size the field afaik. The reason it's sizing itself to any width at all is because font-size is a considerably large size, this makes the field wider. You need to apply a width style to it to make it widen, by the looks of it webkit is the only rendering engine that sizes items if both margin right and left are applied. As for the tabs, use F12 in IE8, it may help determine JS errors.

Comment: Anytime, it's effectively firebug in IE, hope it helps get your problem sorted.